# How to output the current value of an @State property in the Xcode console

Tags: ios, swiftui

When I try to output the value of an @State property in the Xcode console with `po` I get this error:

```
po myValue
error: expression failed to parse:
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  MyApp.MainView.myValue.getter : Swift.Double
```

Tried with `p myValue` but it gives same error, the only way to get something is via

Answer (score 1):

The only working solution for now that I know of is with:

`po _myValue._value`

but I am not sure if this is the correct way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

`@State` is actually a [Property Wrapper](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID617). What that means is, when you create:

```
@State var myValue: T
```

`myValue` is actually a computed property, in the form similar to:

```
var myValue: T {
    get { _myValue.wrappedValue }
    set { _myValue.wrappedValue = newValue }
}
```

Where as the actual property is stored as:

```
var _myValue: State<T>
```

Which is why `po myValue` wasn't working, and you must've used `po _myValue` instead.